# Aplicando una función a cada array de cada par de lineas

Tags: python, python-3.x, imagen, pandas

Tengo una columna de un marco de datos lleno de matrices con imágenes.

```
>>>df.IMAGES.head()

0    ["https://cf-medias.avendrealouer.fr/image/_87...,https://cf-medias.avendrealouer.fr/image/_89...
1    ["http://photos.ubiflow.net/440414/165474561/p...,http://photos.ubiflow.net/440414/azeaze/p
2    ["https://v.seloger.com/s/width/965/visuels/0/...,...
3    ["https://pix.yanport.com/ads/e9e07ed0-812f-11...,...
4    ["https://v.seloger.com/s/width/966/visuels/0/...,...
```

Quiero comprobar si las imágenes de cada pareja de filas son similares. Así que hice una función para comprobar si dos imágenes son similares. ¿Cómo puedo aplicar mi función a cada par de filas?

```
from PIL import Image
import imagehash
import requests
from io import BytesIO

def image_similarity(imageAurl,imageB):
    responseA = requests.get(imageAurl)
    imgA = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
    responseB = requests.get(imageBurl)
    imgB = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))    
    hash0 = imagehash.average_hash(Image.open(imageA)) 
    hash1 = imagehash.average_hash(Image.open(imageB)) 
    cutoff = 5

    if hash0 - hash1 < cutoff:
        print('images are similar')
    else:
        print('images are not similar')
```

Intenté :

```
df['NextImage'] = df['IMAGES'][df['IMAGES'].index - 1]
df['IsSimilar'] = df.apply(lambda x: image_similarity(x['IMAGES'], x['NextImage']), axis=1)
```

Sin embargo, obtengo el siguiente error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidSchema                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-16b99a7b864a> in <module>
      1 df['NextImage'] = df['IMAGES'][df['IMAGES'].index - 1]
----> 2 df['IsSimilar'] = df.apply(lambda x: image_similarity(x['IMAGES'], x['NextImage']), axis=1)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, result_type, args, **kwds)
   6012                          args=args,
   6013                          kwds=kwds)
-> 6014         return op.get_result()
   6015 
   6016     def applymap(self, func):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in get_result(self)
    140             return self.apply_raw()
    141 
--> 142         return self.apply_standard()
    143 
    144     def apply_empty_result(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    246 
    247         # compute the result using the series generator
--> 248         self.apply_series_generator()
    249 
    250         # wrap results

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
    275             try:
    276                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
--> 277                     results[i] = self.f(v)
    278                     keys.append(v.name)
    279             except Exception as e:

<ipython-input-25-16b99a7b864a> in <lambda>(x)
      1 df['NextImage'] = df['IMAGES'][df['IMAGES'].index - 1]
----> 2 df['IsSimilar'] = df.apply(lambda x: image_similarity(x['IMAGES'], x['NextImage']), axis=1)

<ipython-input-21-3acdcb76f890> in image_similarity(imageAurl, imageB)
      7 
      8 def image_similarity(imageAurl,imageB):
----> 9     responseA = requests.get(imageAurl)
     10     imgA = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
     11     responseB = requests.get(imageBurl)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\requests\api.py in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     73 
     74     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
---> 75     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
     76 
     77 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\requests\api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     58     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     59     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 60         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     61 
     62 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    531         }
    532         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 533         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    534 
    535         return resp

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    638 
    639         # Get the appropriate adapter to use
--> 640         adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
    641 
    642         # Start time (approximately) of the request

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in get_adapter(self, url)
    729 
    730         # Nothing matches :-/
--> 731         raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
    732 
    733     def close(self):

InvalidSchema: ('No connection adapters were found for \'["https://cf-medias.avendrealouer.fr/image/_873908158_d.jpg","https://cf-medias.avendrealouer.fr/image/_873908159_d.jpg","https://cf-medias.avendrealouer.fr/image/_873908160_d.jpg","https://cf-medias.avendrealouer.fr/image/_873908161_d.jpg","https://cf-medias.avendrealouer.fr/image/_873908162_d.jpg"]\'', 'occurred at index 0')
```

El error parece ser porque intento tomar la matriz de urls que cada columna tiene para una url.

Comment: Un par de preguntas: 1º Quieres comparar la 0 con la 1, la 0 con la 2, etc, luego la 1 con la 2 la 1 con la 3 etc? 2º Dentro de cada par de listas quieres comparar las que tienen el mismo índice? todas con todas?

Comment: @AdriánSanzWallace Dentro de cada par de listas (cada linea tiene una lista de url) quiero comparar las fotos, para saber cuando hay dos listas que tienen una foto similar. Los urls pueden ser differente cuando las fotos son las mismas en dos par de listas differentes.

Answer (score 0):

A ver si con este ejemplo te valdría para adaptarlo:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations


def comparar(textoA, textoB):
    return True if textoA == textoB else False


def evaluarIguales(df):
    for p in combinations(df['numeros'], 2):
        for n in p[0]:
            for m in p[1]:
                iguales = comparar(n, m)
                # print(n, m, iguales)
                if iguales:
                    return True
        return False


# df1 tiene combinaciones que comparar() evalúa como True
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'numeros': [[0, 10, 5, 2, 1, 7],
                 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                 [8, 7, 3, 9],
                 [7, 4, 2]]})

# df2 no tiene combinaciones que comparar() evalúa como True
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'numeros': [[0, 10, 5, 2, 0, 7],
                 [15, 4, 3, 1, 9],
                 [11, 17, 13, 19],
                 [78, 45, 23]]})


print(evaluarIguales(df1)) # devuelve True
print(evaluarIguales(df2)) # devuelve False
```

la función `comparar()` 'simula' tu función que evalúa si dos imágenes son similares (tendrías que poner que tu función devuelva `True` si son similares y `False` si no lo son, o modificar la función `evaluarIguales`), mientras que `evaluarIguales()` es la que se encarga de hacer las combinaciones en el Dataframe (que tiene una única columna llamada `numeros`).

He definido dos df en el que uno contiene elementos que la función `comparar()` devolvería `True` (df1) y otro en la que ninguna combinación devolvería `True` (df2).

En el momento en el que detecta que alguna de las combinaciones es evaluada por `comparar()` como `True`, detiene la función (puesto que ya no hace falta seguir comprobando) y devuelve `True`, mientras que si ninguna es evaluada así, devolverá `False`, puedes ver el comportamiento descomentando la linea del `print()`.

Por explicar también lo que hace `itertools.combinations` en este caso, recibe un iterable, y crea las posibles combinaciones en tuplas de dos valores (segundo argumento), es decir:

```
for p in combinations(df1['numeros'], 2):
    print(p)
```

Dará como resultado:

```
([0, 10, 5, 2, 1, 7], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
([0, 10, 5, 2, 1, 7], [8, 7, 3, 9])
([0, 10, 5, 2, 1, 7], [7, 4, 2])
([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [8, 7, 3, 9])
([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [7, 4, 2])
([8, 7, 3, 9], [7, 4, 2])
```